# Blazor state not changed after exception

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a component that shows a loading bar, makes a http request and when it's done hides the loading bar. 
When an exception occures the loading bar is not hidden even though my code is in wrapped in try finally block.

```
try
{
    IsLoading = true;
    await httpService.InvokeAsync();
}
finally
{
    IsLoading = false;
    //StateHasChanged();
}
```

If I uncomment `StateHasChanged()` it works as expected. I know my exception is unhandled (and is printed to console) but I'm trying to make some sort of global exception handler and would like to avoid having catch blocks.

Is this expected behaviour? 
Are there any performace issues because of StateHasChanged call in finally block when there is no exception?

Comment: have you checked this?

Comment: oops. i meant to paste this link with my previous comment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: yes, but that does not answer my question...